# How to make a vertical bar chart with two values per every X axis item

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, charts

Below is the sample data and the manipulations done so far. To give context, I have certain industries shown by the code and title. Next, are three time periods (first, second, third). They represent 2020-02-01, 2020-04-01, and 2021-07-01 respectively but I renamed them for ease of processing. The goal is to have a vertical bar chart with the industries left to right with a bar for each the decline and recovery value associated with each. So 2 per industry for a total of eight. So for total nonfarm, there would be two bars next to each other and not stacked on top of each other.

When I do so I get an error about "Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic."
Below is the code that I use to create this chart. Any ideas on how to get around this error?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

seriescode <- c(00,11,22,23)
seriestitle <-c("Total Nonfarm","Mining","Utilities","Construction")
first <- c(100,20,32,44)
second <- c(95,17,25,30)
third <- c(98,18,26,33)


bartest <-data.frame(seriescode,seriestitle,first,second,third)


bartest <- bartest %>% mutate(Decline = first - second)
bartest <- bartest %>% mutate(Recovery = third-second)

bartest <- bartest %>% pivot_longer(cols = Decline:Recovery, names_to = "change_type", values_to = "change")


chart4 <- bartest %>%ggplot(aes(x=seriestitle,y=change, fill = change_type))+geom_bar()+labs(x="Industry",y="Net Change")+scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+ggtitle("Decline and Recovery by Industry")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `geom_col` or change the statistic in `geom_bar`, here is why:

```
?geom_bar
```

> geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of
> cases in each group (or if the weight aesthetic is supplied, the sum
> of the weights). If you want the heights of the bars to represent
> values in the data, use geom_col() instead. geom_bar() uses
> stat_count() by default: it counts the number of cases at each x
> position. geom_col() uses stat_identity(): it leaves the data as is.

Than your result would be this:

### Code

```
bartest %>%
  mutate(
    Decline = first - second,
    Recovery = third-second
    ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Decline:Recovery, names_to = "change_type", values_to = "change") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=seriestitle,y=change, fill = change_type))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  labs(
    title = "Decline and Recovery by Industry",
    x = "Industry",
    y = "Net Change")
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Felix, how would I have the bars next to each other and not stacked on top each other. I need eight in total from left to right... two per seriescode/seriestitle.

Comment: For that @TimWilcox you need to change the argument `position` inside the geometry, in this case would be `position = "dodge"`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

seriescode <- c(00,11,22,23)
seriestitle <-c("Total Nonfarm","Mining","Utilities","Construction")
first <- c(100,20,32,44)
second <- c(95,17,25,30)
third <- c(98,18,26,33)


bartest <-data.frame(seriescode,seriestitle,first,second,third)


bartest <- bartest %>% mutate(Decline = first - second)
bartest <- bartest %>% mutate(Recovery = third-second)
bartest <- bartest %>% pivot_longer(cols = Decline:Recovery, names_to = "change_type", values_to = "change")

bartest %>%
  ggplot(aes(seriestitle, change, fill = change_type)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>